# Is this a good way to prove that $3^x+4^x =5^x $ has $x=2$ as the only real solution?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Divide both sides of the equation $3^x+4^x=5^x$ by $5^x$.

$$ \Rightarrow \frac { 3^x }{ 5^x } +\frac { 4^x }{ 5^x } =\frac { 5^x }{ 5^x }$$
$$\tag1 \Rightarrow \left( \frac 3 5  \right)^x + \left( \frac { 4 }{ 5 }  \right)^x =1$$
$\because \frac { 3 }{ 5 }  \leqslant 1 \Rightarrow \sin \theta =\frac { 3 }{ 5 }$ would be valid.

We know, $\sin^2 \theta +\cos ^2 \theta =1$.

$\Leftrightarrow \cos^2 \theta =1-\sin ^2 \theta$.

$$ \Leftrightarrow \cos \theta =\sqrt { 1- \left( \frac { 3 }{ 5 }  \right)^2 } =\frac { 4 }{ 5 }$$

$\therefore \sin \theta =\frac { 3 }{ 5 } \ \land \ \cos\theta =\frac { 4 }{ 5 }$.

The equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$ \Rightarrow \left( \cos\theta \right)^x + \left( \sin \theta  \right)^x =1.$$

We know that the above equation would hold true for only $ x=2$.

Hence Proved.

Thanks to **lab bhattacharjee** for reminding me to link the question details to other answers.

Please tell me if my answere is better and more reasonable than the other answers on the following pages:

[Prove that $x = 2$ is the unique solution to $3^x + 4^x = 5^x$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272114/prove-that-x-2-is-the-unique-solution-to-3x-4x-5x-where-x-in-mat?lq=1)

[Proving that $ 2 $ is the only real solution of $ 3^x+4^x=5^x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61812/proving-that-2-is-the-only-real-solution-of-3x4x-5x?lq=1)

If it is not the best one, please give the link to the best solution.
Thanks a ton for your time!

Thanks to **Hagen von Eitzen** for reformatting the question details into a better format.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61812/proving-that-2-is-the-only-real-solution-of-3x4x-5x

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sorry, but the question was if my solution was more reasonable than the one's you just provided the link for. Why or Why not?

Comment: At the end there is the assertion that $x=2$ is the only solution of $(\cos \theta)^x+(\sin\theta)^x=1$. This needs to be proved. The introduction of sine and cosine is not really necessary, but is fine if it helps you to visualize.

Comment: You should only put *mathÜ in Latex markup, not *everything*. Legibility really suffers.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry, My fault. I will change it soon as possible. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am grateful to you as you undertook effort to correct my mess. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Sir, isn't ${ \left( \cos { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ x }+{ \left( \sin { \theta  }  \right)  }^{ x }=1$ an identity true for only x=2? I am not really a good student, it'd be nice if you could explain further.

Comment: You need to prove it, that is basically what the problem is about, since verifying that $3^2+4^2=5^2$ is easy. Rewrite as $(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x=1$, use the fact that (for say positive $x$ and $y$) and $0\lt s\lt 1$, if $x\lt y$ then s^x\gt s^y$.

Comment: Or even more intuitive: Consider the form $(3/4)^x+1=(5/4)^x$. Then the left side is decreasing and the right increasing.

Comment: 5 to the power of x divided by 5 to the power of x is always 1. Clearly 5 to the power of x is not 0.
(3/5)^x is strictly decreasing, so is (4/5)^x. Since this function is bijective there can only be one solution.

Comment: Note you are talking about exponential functions not trigonometric functions. The formula cos^2+sin^2=1 requires the number 2. Therefore since x is variable it is not possible to take advantage of that formula.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=(\frac{3}{5})^x+(\frac{4}{5})^x$

This function is strictly decreasing , and as such it's graph will only intersect the line $y=1$ in only one point(suppose there are two points, due to the fact that it is strictly decreasing, these points must coincide).